# Parse withinKilometers returning 500 error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse JavaScript SDK to query one of my tables, and the function that uses withinKilometers is giving me a 500 error every time. I can't seem to understand why. Looking at the documentation, it seems like I'm using withinKilometers correctly. Here's the function:

```
function getPickupPointsInCircle() {
// initialization call
Parse.initialize(some_key, some_other_key);

// table and query
var Table = Parse.Object.extend(pickupTable);
var query = new Parse.Query(Table);
var point = new Parse.GeoPoint(40.73555, -74.00425);
var radius = 1.00364;
query.withinKilometers("pickup_location", point, radius);

// results
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        var res = "Number of pickup points: " + results.length + "\n";
        for(i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
            res += results[i].get("pickup_location").longitude+", "+results[i].get("pickup_location").latitude + "\n";
        alert(res);

    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: can I see your tables? Is there actually a table there, with an object that has the values in the "pickup_location" column?

Comment: I'm not sure how to show you my table, but that column does exist. If I run the query on just that column existing, it works just fine.

Comment: also, if you are using the command line interface going to it and typing in "parse logs" might give you some more information

Comment: Is pickupTable variable defined somewhere else ?

Comment: @ChrisL I just checked the log online and there wasn't anything there. Will the command line show me something different? I haven't used that.

Comment: @curiousgeek That's just a variable with the string of the table in it. I use it for all my other functions without problem.

Comment: Ok as i didn't see it in the codesnippet, i was guessing may be you missed  "" on the name or using an undefined variable.

Comment: I just set everything up on my parse and it works. You have a variable or class name off somewhere. Is the pickupTable variable defined globally or is it in another function?

Comment: @ChrisL The pickupTable variable is defined globally. I use it in my other functions just fine. Could something be wrong with my geopoint or something? I'm almost positive all the class names and stuff are correct.

Comment: The geopoint looks fine and I copied and pasted your code to make it work.

Comment: @ChrisL The weird thing is that the same thing happens when I use withinMiles or withinRadians, but withinGeoBox doesn't have a problem.